# Sinusoid with increasing frequency

Tags: continuous-signals, cosine

How would you describe this signal? It's like a sinusoid but as if its frequency was constantly increasing: could you write down a mathematical description? Thanks. And no, this is not homework...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frequency is more likely decreasing (period is getting longer). This is a sweep sine signal or as some people used to call it - chirp tone. No point in rewriting the literature, so here are some links with very good explanation for both linear and exponential frequency change.

For linear sweep you get:

$$s(t)=\sin\left(\omega_1t+\frac{\omega_2-\omega_1}{T}\cdot \frac{t^2}{2}\right) $$

where:

$\omega_1 $, $\omega_2$ - initial and final angular frequency respectively

$T$  - sweep duration.

> Meng Q., et al. - [*Impulse Response Measurement With Sine Sweeps and
>   Amplitude Modulation
>   Schemes*](http://guillaume.perrin74.free.fr/ChalmersMT2012/Papers/Impulse%20Response/IEEE_2008_LSP_IR_SineSweep.pdf)
>
> Farina A. - [*Advancements in impulse response measurements by sine
>   sweeps*](http://pcfarina.eng.unipr.it/Public/Papers/226-AES122.pdf)

Comment: You will also see it referred to as a Linear Frequency Modulated (LFM) pulse. It is commonly used in Radar and Sonar systems to increase the bandwidth and improve the resulting resolution.